# How would I construct a regular expression to match a word, unless it's a part of a specific pattern?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex that works while I want to match 'android' not followed by 'mobile'

```
(?=.*android)(?!.*mobile)
```

But if the string is a pattern like this- "my-custom-android", I don't want that to have any match with my regex.

```
For example, "my-custom-android some thing else" should not have a match with the regex.
```

** I am looking for an regular expression that's supported by Javascript, currently lookbehind isn't supported in JS **

Comment: `(?=.*android)(?!.*mobile)` matches any string that has `android` and has no `mobile` substrings. Now, what are you trying to achieve? Why shouldn't `my-custom-android` match?

Comment: http://2ality.com/2017/05/regexp-lookbehind-assertions.html

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew
That's true. But it matches "my-custom-android some thing else" too. i need a pattern that will match "android" unless it's part of "my-custom-android"

Comment: @Bergi lookbehind isn't supported on Javascript.

Comment: Sanky, what have you tried to achieve what you need? Please share the current code you are using.

Comment: @Sanky Did you read the linked page?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I don't have any solution for this problem,  I used (?=.*android)(?!.*mobile) to achieve the first scenario.

Comment: But where in? What is the code behind?

Comment: @Bergi yeah ... that's why I said lookbehind is not available in JS

Comment: Anyone who have down voted the question, may you please explain your thought behind this?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew not sure why you require this. Anyway here is a snippet-

var str = "my-custom-android some thing else";
var patt = new RegExp("(?=.*android)(?!.*mobile).*", "i");
var res = patt.test(str);
if(res){
   --do something--
}

Comment: Ok, so you are using the regex with `RegExp#test` method. That clarifies a lot. So, let's precise: you need to only match if there is `android` not followed with `mobile` and only if the `android` is not part of `my-custom-android`, right?

Comment: Yes you are correct.

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/w83qh1mj/, does it pass all (my) test cases correctly?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you for this. Is there anyway to achieve this with RegExp#test? I'm asking this because in my case this test part is in a library so I can't quite change there. I absolutely appreciate your answer and it is correct.

Comment: You cannot use a one step regex because JS regex does not support a lookbehind yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may perform the check without a lookbehind:

```js
var strs =[ "my-custom-android some thing else", "my-custom-android mobile some thing else android", "mobile android", "android mobile", "another android story" ];
var patt = /(my-custom-)?android(?!.*mobile)/i;
for (var str of strs) {
  var res = str.match(patt);
  if(res && res[1] === undefined)
  { // do something
     console.log(str, "=> MATCHED");
  } else {  // DON'T do anything
    console.log(str, "=> NOT MATCHED"); 
  }
}
```

The `/(my-custom-)?android(?!.*mobile)/i` pattern searches for any `my-custom-` (1 or 0 repetitions) followed with `android` that is not followed with `mobile` anywhere after this substring. The `my-custom-` part is *captured* into Group 1 and can be assessed after the match is found. If this group is undefined, it means that the text is missing before `android` and it is a valid match. Else, we should fail that match.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following pattern, using negative lookbehind:

```
(?<!my-custom-)android(?!.*mobile)
```